# Speech Recognition semantic results

Tags: xml, grammar, speech

I'm currently developing a Speech Recognition application and I'm having some problems when obtaining the semantic results. Here's a small sample of my grammar:

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US" root="rootRule" tag-format="semantics/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

<rule id="rootRule">
<one-of>
    <item> <ruleref uri="#age"/> <tag>  AnswerAge </tag> </item>
    <item> <ruleref uri="#room" /> <tag> QuestionRoom  </tag> </item>
</one-of>
</rule>

<!-- CA01b: Answer person age -->
<rule id="age">
<one-of>
<item> my age is </item>
</one-of>
<ruleref uri="#numbers"/>
</rule>

<!-- CA02: Ask for room information -->
<rule id="room">
<one-of>
<item> where is room </item>
</one-of>
<ruleref uri="#numbers"/>
</rule>

<!-- Numbers -->
<rule id="numbers">
<item>
    <one-of>
        <item> four  <tag>4</tag></item>
        <item> five  <tag>5</tag></item>
        <item> six   <tag>6</tag></item>
        <item> seven <tag>7</tag></item>
    </one-of>
</item>
</rule>
</grammar>
```

When posed with the following speech:

```
1. Where is room 4
2. My age is 4
```

I wish to obtain the semantic results:

```
1. QuestionRoom=4
2. AnswerAge=4
```

I've been reading thoroughly Microsoft's documentation on how to obtain such results but had no luck. One possible solution would be to replicate the rule "numbers" for each  present in the rootRule but that's far from being an optimal solution. Anyone happens to know a better way to achieve the same results?

Answer (score -1):

Found the solution for it, used an approach similar to the one used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004390/semantic-interpretation-in-srgs-xml-grammar?rq=1).